# Upgrade from Windows10 PRO N build 1803 to 1903 Error

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, upgrade, updates

Hi I am trying to upgrade to the latest Windows build to be able to get the Windows terminal and because the Windows Update tool is telling me that updates will stop for my current build. However when I am using the [upgrade tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to upgrade, I am getting an hardware incompatability error `0xc0000005` at over 90%.

I am using a MSI GP60 2PE Leopard:

- CPU: i7-4710HQ
- Ram: 16 Gig DDR3
- GPU: Nvidia Geforce 840M
- Boot Disk: Samsung 840 Evo SSD

Do I need to upgrade some drivers? If so which? GPU drivers are up to date. I have tried EVERY hint on the microsoft forums, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visit [this URL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) from a Windows PC to download a tool that lets you create an installation USB for Windows 10. Create it, then open it and run the installer. Hope for success.

If this method doesn't work, I'd try to upgrade to version 1809 first and then to 1903. Unfortunately, Microsoft won't let you download Windows 10 v1809 from that link anymore, so you have to use a workaround. Download a User-agent changer extension for your browser ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher-revived/?src=search), [Chrome (not tested)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=en)) and impersonate Linux. The same link will now let you download an ISO for Windows 10 v1809. Then use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) to create the installer USB.

Comment: While I was preparing for the USB MCT I suddenly was prompted by windows to upgrade. I klicked okay, thinking why no? And it worked for whatever reason..

Comment: @jaaq They may have published a new build with the problem you faced fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The link you showed (Media Creation Link) is the correct link.
From the Microsoft Download site, get the Windows Upgrade Advisor and run it to see if it shows incompatible hardware or software. 
Use the computer manufacturers support tool, or support site(s) to download and install BIOS and all other drivers.

After the above, restart and try updating again. I have V1903 on all my own computers and numerous client computers as well

Please let us know

Comment: I tried multiple times with your solution. No luck at all, always get the same error. Does the new windows build simply not support my hardware anymore??

Comment: @jaaq Your hardware looks rather standard and reasonably modern. It should be supported by Windows 10. Have you tried other methods to upgrade?

Comment: I have tried basically every method I could find on microsoft forums and on the link I shared in the post. The only things I didn't do was reinstall windows from scratch, which I'd like to avoid, and burning a DVD for the upgrade, since I didn't read anywhere that that had any more success than upgrading with the normal tool and I simply didn't want to waste a disk.

Comment: There are some computers that will only upgrade to a certain point. Can you contact your vendor support to verify?

Comment: You can prepare an installer flash drive using the ISO, it works the same way as a DVD would

Comment: You could also try to upgrade ti 1809 first using the flash drive